# Permissions issues on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: apache2.4

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 desktop, and I am attempting to install some composer web projects.

By default, when you run `composer create-project` it installs a 'web' directory inside of your project folder which houses all of the needed public files.

I am trying to get apache to play nicely with this, as the permissions don't allow it by default, apparently.

I have the site installed at /home/'username redacted'/sites/tcrp/web

I have the following .conf setup for the site

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
        # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
        # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
        # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
        # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
        # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
        # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
        ServerName tcrp.localhost

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /home/<username redacted>/sites/thecrewrp/web

        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
        # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
        # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
        # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
        # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
        #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf

        <Directory /home/<username redacted>/sites/thecrewrp/web>
          Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
          AllowOverride All
          Require all granted
          Allow from all
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

Whenever I try to access the site via http://tcrp.localhost, I get a 'Forbidden' error. Now, if I put web files outside of the 'web' folder (for example /home/'username redacted'/sites/blahsite) They are hosted fine, and work. However if I try to place anything inside of the 'web' folder (which is how composer operates), I get a forbidden, followed by 'client denied by server configuration' in the apache error.log file

Comment: It's Bad Practice to use your development environment for production. Better to automate a copy from the development environment to where the web server wants it. Run the automatic copy when the development environment "works".

Comment: Where did you get that I was using my development environment as production? This is being setup on my local development machine. The composer usage is to ensure all depdenencies are built included and working together BEFORE it goes to production.